# Render Google Chart in GWT 2.5 custom cell (I used UiRenderer)

Tags: gwt, cell, google-visualization, gwt-celltable

I am using GWT 2.5 RC1 and GAE 1.7.2.
I created a custom cell using UiRenderer [Rendering HTML for Cells](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder#Rendering_HTML_for_Cells).

I want to render a chart using Google Chart Tools API for GWT [Getting Started Using the Google Chart Tools with GWT](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted)

Below there is snippet of the render method, which does not work.

**Does anybody know, how to render a google chart in a custom cell?**

I would appreciate it, if he/she give me some directions or sample code.
Thanks in advance.

```
    @Override
public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, Value value, final SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    final HTMLPanel test = new HTMLPanel("");
    Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //Panel panel = RootPanel.get();

        // Create a pie chart visualization.
        PieChart pie = new PieChart(createTable(), createOptions());

        pie.addSelectHandler(GoogleCharts.createSelectHandler(pie));
        test.add(pie);
        }
    };
    // Load the visualization api, passing the onLoadCallback to be called
    // when loading is done.
    VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, PieChart.PACKAGE);

    sb.appendHtmlConstant(test.getElement().getInnerHTML());
    renderer.render(sb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a race condition. When you call sb.appendHTMLConstant, the test element is probably empty because the onLoadCallback has not been fired yet. If you move the last two lines to the end of the callback this will remove the race condition.

```
@Override
public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, Value value, final SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    final HTMLPanel test = new HTMLPanel("");

    Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Create a pie chart visualization.
            PieChart pie = new PieChart(createTable(), createOptions());
            pie.addSelectHandler(GoogleCharts.createSelectHandler(pie));
            test.add(pie);

            sb.appendHtmlConstant(test.getElement().getInnerHTML());
            renderer.render(sb);
        }
    };

    // Load the visualization api, passing the onLoadCallback to be called
    // when loading is done.
    VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, PieChart.PACKAGE);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work neither. Line 'renderer.render(sb);' should be outside onLoadCallback(...) method to work properly. Other ideas are welcome.

Comment: When you set a breakpoint on line sb.appendHtmlConstant(test.getElement().getInnerHTML()), what is the content of the test element?

Comment: The content of test element is null.

Comment: What about the contents of pie? Start debugging :)

Comment: The pie is instantiated ok. If I instantiate test element [ HTMLPanel test = new HTMLPanel(""); ] outside onLoadCallback(...) method, when I try .add(Widget widget) method in the onLoadCallback(...) method, the test element is null, nothing is added. But, if I instantiate test element inside onLoadCallback(...) method, then test element content is set properly. After calling sb.appendHtmlConstant(test.getElement().getInnerHTML()); I try to see the content of sb and it returns null!